# Keeping ssh-agent running after closing the console

Tags: windows, zsh, conemu, ssh-agent, cmder

I'm using cmder (ConEmu) as my terminal. My default shell is zsh. I've tried the ssh-agent plugin for zsh, I've tried keychain and I've tried starting ssh-agent manually. No matter what I do, the ssh-agent process quits when I close the console window.

I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior or not, but I want to keep it running once it's started. What could be wrong?

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/a/593042/23334

Comment: @MrStatic It says typing "ssh-agent" will start a process that keeps running after I close the shell. This is true, insofar that if I have multiple tabs with shells open in the same window, closing the one that started the process doesn't end the process. But if I close the whole console window, the process is killed.

Comment: What version of ConEmu you are using? Have you read ConEmu's WhatsNew?

Comment: @Maximus Wow. I swear nothing came up when googling this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have already sorted this from the comments but the solution to this for future visitors is to disable "kill ssh-agent with conemu" in settings->features.

this seems to be enabled on a new install on conemu.